# Python pint objects passed to multiprocessing have different registries than objects created in process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pint

I have an application that requires `multiprocessing` where `pint` objects are passed as arguments to the process and `pint` objects are also created in the process. But these different `pint` objects have different registries from each other.

I expect the unit registry to change in the process due to pickling/unpickling; however, I would expect that the object passed in as argument would have the same registry as the object created in the process. Is there a way to ensure this? Is this an issue with `multiprocessing` or `pint`? Or am I doing something wrong?

Following is a MWE:

```py
import os
import multiprocessing
import pint

ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()


def f(a):
    print("pid in f: ", os.getpid())
    print("ureg in f: ", ureg)
    print("a's ureg in f: ", a._REGISTRY)

    b = ureg.Unit('m')
    print("b's ureg in f: ", b._REGISTRY)
    try:
        print("a == b: ", a == b)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    return b


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("pid: ", os.getpid())
    print("ureg in main: ", ureg)

    a = ureg.Unit('m')
    print("a's ureg in main: ", a._REGISTRY, "\n")

    print("Without multiprocessing...")
    b = f(a)
    print("b's ureg in main: ", b._REGISTRY, "\n")

    print("With multiprocessing...")
    ctx = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn")

    with ctx.Pool(1) as pool:
        p = pool.apply_async(f, (a,))
        b = p.get()
    print("b's ureg in main: ", b._REGISTRY, "\n")
```

With output:

```
pid:  40977
ureg in main:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x7fd1d475ced0>
a's ureg in main:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x7fd1d475ced0> 

Without multiprocessing...
pid in f:  40977
ureg in f:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x7fd1d475ced0>
a's ureg in f:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x7fd1d475ced0>
b's ureg in f:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x7fd1d475ced0>
a == b:  True
b's ureg in main:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x7fd1d475ced0> 

With multiprocessing...
pid in f:  74218
ureg in f:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x7fb5c612fad0>  # Expected to be different from main ureg
a's ureg in f:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x7fb5cba36290>  # Why is this different from previous line?
b's ureg in f:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x7fb5c612fad0>
Cannot operate with Unit and Unit of different registries.  # This error is expected when registries are different
b's ureg in main:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x7fd1d41ca850>  # Why is this different from main process ureg?
```

Comment: Seems like you can just pass the string representation and then re-constitute the object in each process: https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/serialization.html

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, yes, I that would work. In fact, one does not have to pass a string either, but just re-constitute in the process directly: using the above example, `a = ureg.Unit(a)` inside `f` would work. However, I was hoping for a more elegant solution and a detail that perhaps I missed. As it turns out, I did miss something, which your serialization link brought to my attention, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what I was missing was `set_application_registry`. Per the [serialization documentation](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/serialization.html) (thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga),

> However, you have to bear in mind, that the **application registry** is used for unpickling and this might be different from the one that was used during pickling.
>
> ...
>
> If your application needs a single, global registry with custom definitions, you must make sure that it is registered using `pint.set_application_registry()` before unpickling anything.

So, the `multiprocessing` process uses a different registry for unpickling and I can control what that is. Modifying the OP example:

```py
import os
import multiprocessing
import pint

ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
pint.set_application_registry(ureg)


def f(a):
    print("pid in f: ", os.getpid())
    print("ureg in f: ", ureg)
    print("a's ureg in f: ", a._REGISTRY)

    b = ureg.Unit('m')
    print("b's ureg in f: ", b._REGISTRY)
    try:
        print("a == b: ", a == b)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    return b


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("pid: ", os.getpid())
    print("ureg in main: ", ureg)

    a = ureg.Unit('m')
    print("a's ureg in main: ", a._REGISTRY, "\n")

    print("Without multiprocessing...")
    b = f(a)
    print("b's ureg in main: ", b._REGISTRY, "\n")

    print("With multiprocessing...")
    ctx = multiprocessing.get_context("spawn")

    with ctx.Pool(1) as pool:
        p = pool.apply_async(f, (a,))
        b = p.get()
    print("b's ureg in main: ", b._REGISTRY, "\n")
```

yields the expected output:

```
pid:  37081
ureg in main:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x1069cf040>
a's ureg in main:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x1069cf040> 

Without multiprocessing...
pid in f:  37081
ureg in f:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x1069cf040>
a's ureg in f:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x1069cf040>
b's ureg in f:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x1069cf040>
a == b:  True
b's ureg in main:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x1069cf040> 

With multiprocessing...
pid in f:  37083
ureg in f:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x10b9df670>  # Expected to be different from main ureg
a's ureg in f:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x10b9df670>  # This is now the same as the previous line
b's ureg in f:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x10b9df670>  # And so is this
a == b:  True  # Yeah! No error
b's ureg in main:  <pint.registry.UnitRegistry object at 0x1069cf040>  # And this is now the same as the main ureg!
```

I note that with this correction, `a == b` returns `False` in the multiprocessing case for `pint = 0.18` (but no error), but seems to be fixed for `pint >= 0.19`.